# TypeScript: How to import ES6 Map (NetBeans can't find)

Tags: typescript, import, netbeans-8

We switched to from System.js to WebPack, and now NetBeans doesn't know where to find certain types, like `Map` and `Promise`. The compiler is ok. It's just about code completion. I assume it's because the TypeScript plugin only knows how to deal with `systemjs.config.js`.

I have tried this:

```
$ find -name Map*
...
./ui/src/main/webapp/node_modules/rxjs/util/Map.js
./ui/src/main/webapp/node_modules/rxjs/util/Map.d.ts
./ui/src/main/webapp/node_modules/rxjs/src/util/Map.ts
```

So I tried these:

```
//import {Map} from 'rxjs/util/Map'
import {Map} from 'rxjs/src/util/Map'
```

But they are just (respectively)

```
export declare const Map: any
---
export const Map = root.Map || (() => MapPolyfill)();
```

and NetBeans complain on any normal use of the type.
I was also looking at `core-js` (after adding it to systemjs.config.js):

```
import {Map} from 'core-js/modules/es6.map';
```

But NetBeans says 'can't find module ...'.
What should I import to declare `Map` to an unaware tool?

Comment: You don't need to import `Map` and `Promise` if you're targeting `es6`, it is builtin like `Array` and should be available in the `lib.es6.d.ts`. If you don't have them then you are probably not targeting `es6`.

Comment: Right, webpack runs fine, and even `tsc` still compiles without errors, but NetBeans started complaining.

Comment: We were using es6shim. That is simply linked in `index.html`.   In `tsconfig.js` there was, and still is, is `"compilerOptions": {  "target": "es5", ... }` . I am not sure how to make this work, I can't change the target... but somehow, NetBeans were able to find these types before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was, as some suspected, in the NetBeans plugin. NetBeans plugins repository contains an old version.

Downloading the [latest version](https://github.com/Everlaw/nbts/releases) helped.